# how can I fix this loop for my dice rolling problem?

Tags: python

I have this code I wrote partly on my own, and some with help from other posts that I changed. when I type y, while running the program it will continue the loop, but when I say yes it exits. Is there a different input I need? How can I fix this code?

```
from random import randint
repeat = 'y'
while repeat == ('y' or 'yes'):
    print('your dice is',randint(1,6))
    print('Do you want to roll again?')
    repeat = input().lower()
else:
    print('have a nice day')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `repeat == ('y' or 'yes'):`

You'll either want to test the user input against each valid string, like this:

```
while repeat == 'y' or repeat == 'yes':
```

or maybe easier to test against the strings in a list:

```
while repeat in ['y', 'yes']:
```

Hope that helps.